# Firebase Realtime Database - on event - difference between Javascript Deltasnapshot and Android Java DataSnapshot

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For Firebase Realtime Database, everytime new data is added, it creates a `DeltaSnapshot` for '`functions`' and `DataSnapshot` for Android app. Documentation of the two reveal that the javascript functions based DeltaSnapshot also receives something called `event.Data.previous` which stores the prior value of the node. I can't find an equivalent in the Android documentation. Is the difference intentional? If yes, why?
Or is there a workaround/alternative way for Java that I am not able to find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `DeltaSnapshot` is only available in Cloud Functions for Firebase, it is only [documented in the Functions SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DeltaSnapshot).

A `DeltaSnapshot` contains information about the new value of the node and the previous value of the node. This allows you to derive information about the type of update that your Cloud Functions code is processing.

For more information, see the [Cloud Functions documentation on handling event data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#handle_event_data).

Comment: Thanks Frank for the reply. So is there any alternative to DeltaSnapshot in Android? The convenience and flexibility of Deltasnapshot is remarkable.

Comment: There is no `DeltaSnapshot` for the Android SDK, nor for any of the other client SDKs. While it's definitely a nifty class, I've never had a requirement that I couldn't implement without it. If you do, I'd suggest to open a new question with your actual underlying problem.